# SwiftUI: how to dynamically ignoring safe areas on IOS 16

Tags: ios, swiftui, fullscreen

I'm looking for SwiftUI solution to dynamically change the fullscreen of the View/application in IOS 16. For simplicity, consider that a button will toggle go fullscreen or not . I've tried to use Binding values;

```
 var body : some View {
   
   @Binding var fullScreen  = false
   HStack() {

       Button(action: {
          fullScreen.toggle()
       }) {
          Text("Fullscreen Toggle")
       }
   }
   .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(fullScreen == true ? [.all] : [])

 }
```

This was the attempt to solve it, unfortunately, there is no such mode (Runtime);

```
invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to CFRunLoopRunSpecific - break on 
_CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug. This message will only appear once per execution.
```

1. How can we dynamically ignore the safe areas to go full-screen and back in a view.
2. If possible, can we make an app-wide solution instead of a single view?

Note that the solution must be in IOS 16.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this solution will help?

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyFullScreenApp: App {
@State private var isFullScreen = false

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView(isFullScreen: $isFullScreen)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
    .onChange(of: isFullScreen) { newValue in
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }
}}

struct ContentView: View {
@Binding var isFullScreen: Bool
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("This is some content")
        Button(action: {
            isFullScreen.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Toggle Fullscreen")
        }
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .background(Color.white)
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(isFullScreen ? .all : [])
    .statusBar(hidden: isFullScreen)
    .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
}}
```

To enable fullscreen mode, we use the .edgesIgnoringSafeArea() modifier with the .all option, and we hide the status bar using the .statusBar(hidden:) modifier. Note that this will also hide the navigation bar if your view is embedded in a NavigationView.

To make this a global solution for your app, you can create a custom AppDelegate and set the rootViewController of the window property to a new UIHostingController instance that wraps your ContentView. Then you can use the same approach to toggle fullscreen mode.

Answer (score 1):

`... to dynamically ignoring safe areas on IOS 16`, try this very simple approach, where you have the `@Binding var fullScreen: Bool` outside the `body` of the view.
and pass the binding from the parent view, as shown.

Works well for me, on MacOS 13.3, using Xcode 14.3 beta, tested on real ios 16 devices, and macCatalyst.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var fullScreen = false // <-- here
    var body : some View {
        TestView(fullScreen: $fullScreen)  // <-- here
    }
}

struct TestView: View {
    @Binding var fullScreen: Bool  // <-- here
    
    var body : some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(.yellow)
               .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(fullScreen ? [.all] : [])  // <-- here
            Button("Change edgesIgnoringSafeArea") {
                fullScreen.toggle()
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        // .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(fullScreen ? [.all] : [])  // <-- or here
    }
}
```

Comment: I think, ZStack is also a key here. It works even the .frame.